# Erro de acentuação ao utilizar o cURL

Tags: php, libcurl

Boa tarde, tudo bem?

Estou tentando puxar algumas informações via cURL do site dos correios, entretanto está me retornando mas com erro de acentuação, teria alguma forma de alterar o cabeçalho que está vindo de la para corrigir esse problema dos acentos?

Estou puxando dessa forma:

```
<?php

$codigoRastreio = urlencode($_GET['cod']);
$post = array('Objetos' => $codigoRastreio);
// iniciar CURL
$ch = curl_init();
// informar URL e outras funções ao CURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/resultado_semcontent.cfm");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
// Acessar a URL e retornar a saída
$output = curl_exec($ch);
// liberar
curl_close($ch);
// Imprimir a saída
echo $output;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Já consegui corrigir, segue o codigo atualizado:

```
$codigoRastreio = urlencode($_GET['cod']);
$post = array('Objetos' => $codigoRastreio);
// iniciar CURL
$ch = curl_init();
// informar URL e outras funções ao CURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/resultado_semcontent.cfm");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
// Acessar a URL e retornar a saída
$output = curl_exec($ch);
// liberar
curl_close($ch);
// Imprimir a saída
echo utf8_encode($output);
```

Comment: vocẽ não quer comentar o que você mudou no código que funciona?
Sem nada escrito obriga os outros a tentarem comparar os programas inteiros - e não ajuda muito quem tiver a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Claro que comento sim o que fiz, somente inclui esse código urlencode() onde eu estou puxando o get e inclui esse utf8_encode() que foi o principal responsável por funcionar.